# read_csv issue in R Evaluation error: Column 1 must be named

Tags: r, csv

I am new to R and am trying to read a csv file that contains data in one column separated by commas and within quotes similar to this:

```
"First Name", "Last Name", "City", "State", "Country", "Zip Code"
"Amy", "Smith", "San Fransisco", "California", "USA", "10000"
"John", "Parker", "New York", "New York", "USA", "10010"
"Homer", "Smith", "New Haven", "Connecticut", "USA", "21292"
```

How do I import the file so that the commas become columns and the quotes dissappear?

```
First Name   Last Name     City          State     Country   Zip Code
 Amy           Smith   San Fransisco   California    USA       10000
 John         Parker     New York       New York     USA       10010
 Homer         Smith     New Haven     Connecticut   USA       21292
```

I tried

```
read_csv("path to my file.csv", col_names= TRUE, col_types = NULL, header = FALSE)
```

but I get :

```
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  col_character()
)
Error in read_tokens_(data, tokenizer, col_specs, col_names, locale_,  : 
  Evaluation error: Column 1 must be named.
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the csv has all data on a single line?

Comment: You need to add commas between values that don't have them. Example "10000" "John" => "10000","John"

Comment: Doesn't just `read_csv("path to my file.csv")` work for you? It will remove the quotes automatically. Your sample at least doesn't really look like one column. That looks like 6 columns separated by commas (like a real CSV).

Comment: @MrFlick I see that you edited the data but given that the poster mentioned that it was "one column" i suspected that they actually had a poorly formatted csv without newlines

Comment: @CalumYou I just intended what was there. I didn't add any new lines. I think it was just an inaccurate description of what was there.

Comment: @MrFlick sorry I meant newlines as in `\n`, not as in extra data. Hence why I asked if all data was on a single line and would need to split into multiple lines. otherwise i would not be sure why using read_csv directly wouldn't work.

Comment: Thank you for editing the data. yes the data is all in one column not 6 separate columns: the First Name, Last Name, City, State, Country, and Zip Code are all in the same column but separated by commas only.  

I am not sure why read_csv does not work. When I try it, I get the error: Parsed with column specification: cols( col_character() ) Error in read_tokens_(data, tokenizer, col_specs, col_names, locale_, : Evaluation error: Column 1 must be named. –

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue reading in a tsv. I changed the file encoding to UTF-8 and that solved it for me. 
Not elegant, but I did this: 
1) Opened file in Sublime Text
2) Saved as "UTF-8"

Worked for me...